# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Bebidas

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

Here is where the code is throwing the error:

```
public class ArrayPila<E extends Bebidas> implements Pila<E>{
  private static final int TAMAÑO=5;
  private E []arP;
  private int tope;

  public ArrayPila() {
    arP=(E[]) new Object[TAMAÑO];
    tope=-1;        
  }
}
```

I'm just creating a generic stack with a type of object (created in another class) and it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lmis.java.clases.Bebidas;
    at mis.java.estructuras_de_apoyo.ArrayPila.<init>(ArrayPila.java:13)
    at mis.java.miformulario.VentanaP.<init>(VentanaP.java:67).
```

Could you please help?

Comment: You can't cast "down". `E` is a potential subclass of `Object`.

Comment: and how could i fix it then?

Comment: Have you tried `new Bebidas[TAMAÑO]`? In fact, you should probably define `arP` as `Bebidas[]` instead of `E[]` as the only thing you know about `E` is that it is a `Bebidas` subclass.

Comment: i couldn't cast the E so i erased extends and it worked